# "What did you there"

Tags: history

A common nursery rhyme goes like this:

> *Pussy cat, pussy cat, where have you been?
>
>   I’ve been down to London to visit the Queen.
>
>   Pussy cat, pussy cat, what did you there?
>
>   I frightened a little mouse, under her chair.*

My question is:

Was the formulation *what did you there* (as opposed to *what did you **do** there*) current in earlier English?

Comment: See also https://english.stackexchange.com/q/77760/3696 concerning the nursery rhyme "*Pussy cat, pussy cat, where have you been?
I’ve been down to London to visit the Queen.
Pussy cat, pussy cat, **what did you there**?
I frightened a little mouse, under her chair.*"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, of course. Early Modern English used to form questions like German or Spanish, by inverting the subject and the verb. In this case the verb is *did*, the subject is *you*.

Modern English, however, may only invert the subject with the first auxiliary verb, and if there are no auxiliary verbs, must use *Do*-Support to provide a dummy auxiliary *do* to carry the tense.

- Gm: *Wann gehst du?*
- Sp: *¿Cuándo vas (tú)?*
- EMEng: *When goest thou?*
- MEng: *When **do** you go?*