# Inversion or no inversion after "only"?

Tags: adverbs, subject-verb-inversion

> - Only now you can even get them on top of wrinkles.
> - Only infrequently does it happen.

As one of our members has said, inversion happens when a sentence starts with "only" and never otherwise. So why does no inversion happen in the first sentence?

Comment: When *only* is a conjunction, it means *but*. When *only* is an adverb, it means *just*.

Comment: It happens alright if "only now can you get them" is what you want to express. It's just that "only now you can get them" means a different thing. The *even* amplifies that meaning. In fact, "only now can you even get them" is not possible, because contradictory.

Comment: You’ve asked 4 very similar questions all together. Are you sure you meant to do that?

Comment: In the second sentence, *only* modifies the adverb *infrequently*.  In @RegDwight's example, *only* modifies the adverb *now*. In the first sentence, where you don't use inversion, *only* is a conjunction that connects the previous sentence to this one.

Comment: Subject-Auxiliary Inversion is governed by quite a few constructions -- [Yes/No Questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/77762/15299), [Wh-Questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/81629/15299), [Tag Questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/78591/15299), and [Negative Adverb Preposing](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/87422/15299), for a start.

Comment: Dear nima, you seem to be rather confused how this site is supposed to work. You keep posting answers to other users' comments as separate questions. So now not only yourself, but absolutely everyone involved is plenty confused. Please do not split up a single discussion into an indefinite amount of separate posts like that. Address comments directly right there where you read them. I have now merged all your posts back into one.

Answer (score 2):

When I first saw *only now you can get them* I though it was ungrammatical, because, as you say, *only* normally triggers inversion.

However, it is grammatical on a different reading. In everyday speech, *only* can also function as a conjunction, with a meaning similar to *but*. There will be a different stress:

*Only now can you get them*

with even stress on *only* and *now*, means "You can get them now, but you could not get them before".

*Only[,] now you can get them*

with *only* unstressed and probably rather quick, and possibly in a separate breath group (represented by a comma in writing), means "Contrary to what has just been suggested, you can get them now".

Answer (score 0):

Inversion happens when a sentence starts with "only" and never otherwise. 
Eg:

> Only if you come with me, will I go there.

vs

> I will go there only if you come with me.

This is true of many other negative adverbs like "never", "under no circumstance", "rarely" etc.